# c# Chart.Js and JSON with NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net, chart.js

I'm working into Chart.js with VisualStudio, c# and NewtonSoft.Json.
I've written a class which is returning a valid JSON-String. Just checked it here:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
The JSON-String contains the whole data for Chart.js and Looks like this:

```
{
    "labels": [
        "O",
        "N",
        "U",
        "G"
    ],
    "datasets": [
        {
            "label": 2016,
            "fillColor": "rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.2)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1",
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
            "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1",
            "data": [
                2,
                0,
                14,
                16
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I've written a small Ajax-Script in my cshtml. Looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'JSON/kvp_stats.cshtml',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                var d = data;
                alert(d);
                var ctx = $('#myChart');
                var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: d
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Etwas klappt nicht!');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the kvp_stats.cshtml I did following: just wrote:
`@mm_json.getJSON_Kvp(2016)` To Get the returned JSON-String.

Unfortunately the jquery-ajax doesn't seem to accept the data as JSON-data, because it runs into error-function.
When I Change the dataType into html it runs into success.

I think that I have to "Encode" the data to have the dataType respond correctly to the JSON-String but how and where?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll need to use a Controller to send your JSON data back, not a .cshtml. So your URL should be something like "/YourControllerName/GetStats" which will send back the appropriate JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm suprised by myself.
Just found out how to solve the Problem.

The Output of the string in the json-file in my case the `kvp_stats.cshtml` has to be rendered as follows:

`@Html.Raw(mm_json.getJSON_Kvp(2016))` instead of only `@mm.json.getJSON_Kvp`(2016)